# FullCalendar (JQuery) -- Highlight Clicked Event POSSIBLE?

Tags: jquery, css, click, fullcalendar, highlight

I am using the Jquery FullCalendar tool.  I like to CSS highlight the clicked event.  I am currently using the eventClick callback to modify the (this) object but this is useless if the event object spans multiple rows.  Is there a proper way to highlight all parts of the event using CSS and if possible remove the highlight if another event is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

eventRender gets called for each "segment" of the event, so if your event spans 2 rows, it gets called twice for the same event (gut with a different browser element).  So you should simply highlight all events that are passed to you.

In your eventClick, set some variable that you later read in eventRender to determine if you want to highlight the event or not.